# Kali Linux se Conecta y Desconecta de la Red Wifi

Tags: kali-linux

Recientemente me he descargado Kali Linux con el ISO de la página original de Kali y he creado una máquina virtual con Virtual Box . Después he instalado los drivers del adaptador de wifi que tengo que es el alfa awus036ach. También he cambiado la conexión a una conexión puente que estaba por defecto como una conexión NAT.

En Kali puedo ver todas las redes wifi no obstante siempre da uno de los siguientes problemas: (1) Se queda cargando la conexión y al final no se conecta o (2) tarda mucho en conectarse y se desconecta en uno o dos minutos.

Si alguien conoce la solución para este problema apreciaria mucho que me ayudara ya que llevo mucho tiempo intentando arreglar este problema.

Adjunto aquí unas fotos en relación al problema:

'https://ibb.co/kDX8cM5 https://ibb.co/6Y4ttt1 [https://ibb.co/2FDMbtj'](https://ibb.co/2FDMbtj%27)

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no parece ajustarse a [ask]

Comment: Hola! Es complicada la situación para este tipo de preguntas, pues no hay un SuperUser en español para remitirte, pero tampoco está relacionada con programación por ninguna parte. Es posible que termine cerrada por ello. Si aquí o en otro lugar alguien intenta ayudarte, necesitas mucho más que "se queda cargando", sobre todo lidiando con Kali linux, que tiene una audiencia muy específica. Si no dominas distribuciones *nix, podríás comenzar con otra más sencilla?

Comment: Hola! Como bien comenta @Alfabravo es una situación un poco complicada, puesto que, la explicación al problema no es muy descriptiva y por otro lado, la distribución que estás empleando tiene un audiencia muy específica. No obstante, podrías probar a ejecutar el comando "nmcli d" el cual te muestra información sobre los dispositivos de red, donde te aparece si la tarjeta de red de tu equipo está conectada o no y por otro lado, ejecutar el comando "nmtui" el cual te permite a través de una interfaz gráfica muy simple administrar los dispositivos de red.

Comment: En esta interfaz de red, puedes entre otras cosas, activar o modificar una conexión y establecer el nombre de anfitrión del sistema. Yo tuve un problema similar en una distro de Red Hat y pude solventarlo haciendo uso de estos comandos. Suerte!!